# Middlecoin vs Wafflepool vs multipool.us

Tags: litecoin, scrypt, altcoin, pool-payout-methods

Which one actually has a better payoff? As I understand from their websites, their fees are:

```
Middlecoin  3.88%
Wafflepool  1%
Multipool.us    1.50%
```

So, clearly Wafflepool's the best, but how are their respective "algorithms"? Are they making the right mining decisions - does somebody have some empirical evidence of that?

Comment: I've also had questions on this... I've tried multipool.us and wasn't happy with my return. Middlecoin was pretty good until last weekend where my return was about 50% from what it was before... I was thinking of trying Wafflepool. It sucks because I have over 10MHs and most of these places only say between 5-8MH/s, when clearly my miners are reporting 10MH/s+.

Comment: I haven't tried multipool and middlecoin has been having a lot of server trouble. I've switched / am exploring wafflepool and it seems like a much more decent experience!

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but can anyone check that [wafflepool](http://wafflepool.com/) is online? As far as I can see, it is down.